# How to plot hexagon to represent scores on ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis, arcmap

I want to plot hexagon to represent each point's scores in different aspects and show it on the map. Each score will be saved in the data table. How to plot them? Or are there any symbol which can has same effect like hexagon?

[image: hexagon]

Comment: I searched but found out that it was all about how to plot hexagon grids but what I want is to plot hexagon and each corner of it represents the score of its judging criteria. In other words, it may not have to be hexagon, any other shapes, like star, pie, also can work.

Comment: There are a lot more ArcMap questions asked and answered at the [gis.se] Stack Exchange than here.